# Creating polygon in turf surrounding route generated by OSRM?

Tags: leaflet, turf

I am generating a route using the osrm rendering it by leaflet, and I was trying to create a  buffer automatically surrounding this route

[image]

As you can see in the previous image, there are parts of the route that are not inside the buffer generated by turf.

Does anyone know some router that can generate me more points of the route so the buffer can be more precise?